# How to expand a bottom listview item upward?

Tags: android, listview, height

I have a listview, and wanna change the height of the item when clicking it and the clicked item goes to the center of the screen. When clicking the top ones, the item inreasing it's height downward, it looks ok, but the problem is, when clicking the bottom ones, the view is increased also downward, how can it upward when the item is below the screen center?

The main code is:

```
Animation a = new Animation(){
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, 
                                                     Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(0.5*mHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(2000);
    v.startAnimation(a);
```

}

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `smoothScrollBy`, `smoothScrollToPosition` and other methods which is used for scrolling. The main idea is to use scroll down, to make your view completely visible. To do this you have to compute how much you need to scroll to make item visible.